# Что не так не так с кодом java в идее?

Tags: java

Что не так с кодом? Как я понимаю, компилятор с идеи на пару видит только объявление переменной и блок кода, но не соединяет их.

```
    private static ArrayList<BufferedImage> SliceField (BufferedImage imgA) {
        List<BufferedImage> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BufferedImage card = imgA.getSubimage(xStartField + (cardWidth + spacePlease) * i + i,
                    yStartField, cardWidth, cardHeight);
            cards.add(card);
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

Comment: Что не так с кодом не знаю, но могу сказать, что не так с вопросом: он непонятен.

Comment: Вы возвращаете List а система будет ждать ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Измените тип возвращающего значения метода с ArrayList на List. Ну или в вашем методе вместо того что-бы присваивать ссылке интерфейсного типа List объект класа ArrayList(вы можете делать это потому что клас ArrayList реализует интерфейс List), просто замените тип ссылки в методе на ArrayList.

**Пример замены типа возвращаемого значения метода:**

```
private static List<BufferedImage> SliceField (BufferedImage imgA) { // в качестве возвращаемого значения теперь ожидается List<BufferedImage>
        List<BufferedImage> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BufferedImage card = imgA.getSubimage(xStartField + (cardWidth + spacePlease) * i + i,
                    yStartField, cardWidth, cardHeight);
            cards.add(card);
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

**Пример замены типа ссылки с List на ArrayList**

```
private static ArrayList<BufferedImage> SliceField (BufferedImage imgA) {
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> cards = new ArrayList<>(); // тут меняем с List<BufferedImage> на ArrayList<BufferedImage>
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BufferedImage card = imgA.getSubimage(xStartField + (cardWidth + spacePlease) * i + i,
                    yStartField, cardWidth, cardHeight);
            cards.add(card);
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

Для большего понимания происходящего почитайте про наследование и полиморфизм, а так вообще в часности про OOP. Могу порекомендовать книгу K. Syerra "Изучаем Java", очень даже хорошо и на пальцах объясняется основные принципы OOP и вообще учит програмировать в целом.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает(( Почему-то за пределами метода main всё работает

Comment: В каком плане за пределами метода main? Покажите полную реализацию вашего кода в плоть с класом и собственно методом main